# How to solve customer_id error in google ads api(python)

Tags: python, google-ads-api

Try running the example [get_campaign.py](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/master/examples/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py) in the google ads api.
The code was entered as follows

```
import argparse
import sys

from google.ads.google_ads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.google_ads.errors import GoogleAdsException


def main(client, customer_id):
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService", version="v6")

    query = """
        SELECT campaign.id, campaign.name
        FROM campaign
        ORDER BY campaign.id"""

    # Issues a search request using streaming.
    response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id, query=query)

    try:
        for batch in response:
            for row in batch.results:
                print(
                    f"Campaign with ID {row.campaign.id} and name "
                    f'"{row.campaign.name}" was found.'
                )
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print(
            f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status '
            f'"{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:'
        )
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print(f"\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}")
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # GoogleAdsClient will read the google-ads.yaml configuration file in the
    # home directory if none is specified.
    google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage('C:/Users/GoogleAPI/googleads.yaml')

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Lists all campaigns for specified customer."
    )
    # The following argument(s) should be provided to run the example.
    parser.add_argument(
        "-c",
        "--customer_id",
        type=str,
        required=True,
        help="The Google Ads customer ID.",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.customer_id)
    main(google_ads_client, args.customer_id)
```

But I get this error.

```
 errors {
  error_code {
    authorization_error: USER_PERMISSION_DENIED
  }
  message: "User doesn\'t have permission to access customer. Note: If you\'re accessing a client customer, the manager\'s customer id must be set in the \'login-customer-id\' header. See https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/d
ocs/concepts/call-structure#login-customer-id"
}
```

customer id works fine for google adwords api.

If anyone knows the answer, I would appreciate it if you let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @PeterRing I have added the answer, Peter. If it isn't solved yet!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need is to pass the CustomerID without dash (-). More specifically, you just need passing the CustomerID with `XXXXXXXXXX` format instead of `XXX-XXX-XXXX`. The documentation isn't that informative!